# tailwind Footer Content not fixed on bottom on mobile

Tags: css, tailwind-css, responsive

I've run into a bit of a snag with my Tailwind CSS page. So, when I toss in some content at the bottom, everything looks spick and span on desktop, but when it comes to mobile, it decides to play hide-and-seek and positions itself smack in the center instead of obediently staying at the bottom. I've dabbled in various fixes, even tried my hand at the elusive absolute solution, but no luck so far. Any wizardry or extra advice you could throw my way would be a real lifesaver! Thanks

```
<body class="bg-black h-screen">
    <div class="w-full  h-[300px] sticky top-0" >

    <nav class="nav fixed w-full h-[200px] p-5 shadow md:flex md:items-center md:justify-between">
 
             <img src="logo3-removebg-preview (1).png" class="" alt="" width="200px" height="200px">
           <ul class="md:flex md:items-center hidden ">
            <li class="mx-4"><a href="#" class="text-white">Home</a></li>
            <li class="mx-4"><a href="#" class="text-white">About</a></li>
            <li class="mx-4"><a href="#" class="text-white">Services</a></li>
            <li class="mx-4"><a href="#" class="text-white">Projects</a></li>
            <li class="mx-4"><a href="#" class="text-white">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
 
    </nav>
</div>

 

     <section class="grid grid-rows-2 w-full h-[500px] pt-20 ">

    <div class="header-text w-full h-1/2 space-y-36 space-x-2 col-span-3 ">
        <div class="img grid place-content-center w-full h-1/2">
            <img src="img1.png" alt="" class="img1" width="300">
        </div>
        <div class="txt text-center   text-white">

            <h1>Hi, I'm <span class="text-xl font-bold" style="color: #ff0051;"> Mohssen</span>  from Morocco</h1>
        <p>Full Stack Developper & IT Specialist</p>
    </div>

</div>
</section>
<section>
    <div class="p1 text-white">
        <img class="pb-8 pt-2" src="webdev.png" alt="" srcset="">
        <h1 class="text-center pb-4 ">About<span class="ml-2" style="color: #ff0051;">Me</span></h1>
                <div class="titles grid grid-cols-3 place-content-center text-center gap-0 pb-6 pt-4">
            <h4>Skilles</h4>
            <h4>Experience</h4>
            <h4>Education</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="data text-center text-white">
        <h5 class="redd">Web Development</h5>
        <h2>Web app Development</h2>  
            <h5 class="redd pt-4">Web Development</h5>
        <h2>IT Maintenance</h2>  
            <h5 class="redd pt-4">Networking</h5>
        <h2>Web app Development</h2>
    </div>
</section>
<section class="w-full min-h-screen">
    <h1 class="text-white text-center pb-8 pt-8">My Services</h1>

    <div class="divs grid md:grid-cols-3  place-content-center gap-y-12 text-center text-white">
      <div class="web text-center rounded-3xl   w-[350px] h-[270px] bg-slate-600"  >
            <div class="img grid place-content-center pb-4 gap-6 pt-8">

            <img src="2282188-removebg-preview (1).png" alt="" srcset="" width="100px" height="100px">
        </div>

        <h3 class="pb-4">Web Devlopment</h3>
        <p  class="">Building websites and web apps with latest web technologys react and laravel,bootsrap...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="IT text-center grid place-content-center rounded-3xl gap-6 w-[350px] h-[270px] bg-slate-600">
        <div class="img grid place-content-center ">

             <img src="computer_icon_129107.png" alt="" width="100px" height="100px">
        </div>
        <h3>IT Support</h3>
        <p>install and Repair major problems of computers and pc equipment ..</p>
    </div>

    <div class="Networking text-center grid place-content-center rounded-3xl w-[350px] h-[270px] bg-slate-600">

        <div class="img grid place-content-center pb-8">
             <img class="  " src="computer-network-51-removebg-preview.png" alt="" width="100px" height="100px">
        </div>
        <h3 class="pb-4">Networking</h3>
        <p>install and repair computer network and secure network</p>
    </div>
</div>

</section>

<section class="w-full h-screen text-white text-center pt-8">
    <h1 class="pb-8">My Projects    </h1>

    <div class="allp grid grid-cols-1 sm:grid-cols-2 md:grid-cols-3 lg:grid-cols-4 gap-2">

        <div class="p1 w-[370px] h-[450px] hover:scale-125">
            <img class="rounded-2xl" src="music store.png" alt="" srcset="">
            <div class="overlay grid grid-rows-2 text-center place-content-center ">
                <h3>Music E-commerce </h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam dolorum aut nam!</p>
            </div>
    </div>

        <div class="p1  w-[350px] h-[450px]">
                  <img src="py web.png" alt="" srcset="">
                  <div class="overlay grid grid-rows-2 text-center place-content-center ">
                    <h3>Music E-commerce </h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam dolorum aut nam!</p>
                </div>
  
        </div>
        <div class="p1  w-[350px] h-[450px]">
            <img src="store.png" alt="" srcset="">
            <div class="overlay grid grid-rows-2 text-center place-content-center ">
                <h3>Music E-commerce </h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam dolorum aut nam!</p>
            </div>
    </div>  
        <div class="p1  w-[350px] h-[450px]">
                 <img src="p py.png" alt="" srcset="" height="150px" >
                 <div class="overlay grid grid-rows-2 text-center place-content-center ">
                    <h3>Music E-commerce </h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam dolorum aut nam!</p>
                </div>
         </div>    
    
         <div class="p1  w-[350px] h-[450px]">
                 <img src="food store.png" alt="" srcset="">
                 <div class="overlay grid grid-rows-2 text-center place-content-center ">
                    <h3>Music E-commerce </h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam dolorum aut nam!</p>
                </div>
         </div>   
           <div class="p1  w-[350px] h-[450px]" >
                 <img src="ab.png" alt="" srcset="">
                 <div class="overlay grid grid-rows-2 text-center place-content-center ">
                    <h3>Music E-commerce </h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam dolorum aut nam!</p>
                </div>
         </div>     
         <div class="p1  w-[350px] h-[450px]">
                 <img src="film.png" alt="" srcset="">
                 <div class="overlay grid grid-rows-2 text-center place-content-center ">
                    <h3>Music E-commerce </h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam dolorum aut nam!</p>
                </div>
         </div>  
        
    </div>
</section>

 
<section class="footer sm:w-full md:w-1/2 lg:w-1/3 xl:w-1/4 h-[300px] sticky bottom-0">

    <div class="contacto w-full h-[300px] flex flex-col">
        <div class="contacto w-full h-[300px] flex flex-col items-center">
            <form class="text-center" action="#"  method="post">
            <input type="text" name="" id="" placeholder="Name">
            <input type="text" name="" id="" placeholder="Email">
            <textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Message">
            </textarea>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="social mt-auto text-white mx-4">
         <h3>Contact Me</h3>
 
        <i class="fa-brands fa-facebook mr-6"></i>
        <i class="fa-brands fa-linkedin-in mr-6"></i>
        <i class="fa-brands fa-square-twitter"></i>
    </div>
</div>
</section>
 
</body>
```

help please on mobile footer moved up to center

Answer (score 0):

In the footer section classes, replace `sticky` with `fixed`

Comment: nothing footer disappeared after using fixed.

Comment: what version of tailwind are you using? Can you reproduce the issue on Codepen? Possibly, also try explicitly setting the footer position on mobile i.e. `sm:sticky`

Comment: https://codepen.io/Jaafar-Hamdouch/pen/xxBzjmd

Comment: as you see sm:sticky not helping

Comment: solved by removing h-screen from  projects grid chat gpt cannot find the bug haha